# Further refining the signature of a nested module in the signature of the parent

Tags: ocaml

I have an ML file which contains a nested module. For example:

```ml
let f n = n + 1

module type M_type = sig
  val g : int -> int
  val h : int -> int
end

module M : M_type = struct
  let g n = n + 2
  let h n = n + 3
end

let j n = n |> M.h |> M.g |> f
```

When writing an MLI for this ML, I wish not to expose `M.h`, but I do wish to expose `M.g`.

Such as the following:

```ml
module type M_type = sig
  val g : int -> int
end

module M : M_type

val j : int -> int
```

The above combination of ML and MLI does not compile.

The idea is that my nested module `M` contains some functions that I do wish to expose to other functions in the parent module, but not to a user of the parent module.

Is there a legal way to achieve this? If there is none, what is the best alternative to achieve this kind of narrowing of the signature?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you add `reason` as a tag since he's clearly talking about an OCaml problem? Are you trying to advertise it? Well, I guess the `ocaml` tag will now be poluted by your editings...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look closely at the compiler error:

```
 Module type declarations do not match:
         module type M_type = sig val g : int -> int val h : int -> int end
       does not match
         module type M_type = sig val g : int -> int end
```

you will see that the compiler does not complain about the module `M`, but about the module type `M_type`.

Indeed, the definition of the two module type does not match:

```
module type M_type = sig
  val g : int -> int
  val h : int -> int
end
```

is not compatible with

```
module type M_type = sig
  val g : int -> int
end
```

There are many ways to fix this problem.
One possibility is to not use module type as signature constraint when unneccessary:

```
(* a.ml *)
module M = struct
  let g n = n + 2
  let h n = n + 3
end
```

Similarly, the mli file can be written as

```
(*a.mli*)    
module M : sig val g: int -> int end
```

Another possibility is to only define the constrained module type

```
(* a.ml *)
module type M_type = sig val g: int -> int end
module M: sig include M_type val h: int -> int end =
(* Note that the signature constraint above is not necessary *)
struct
  let g n = n + 2
  let h n = n + 3
end
```

with the associated mli file:

```
(*a.mli*)
module type M_type = sig val h: int -> int end    
module M : sig val g: int -> int end
```

It is also possible to define an extended module type `EXT` for the `.ml` file:

```
module type M_type = sig val g: int -> int end
module type EXT = sig include M_type val h: int -> int end
module M: EXT = struct
  let g n = n + 2
  let h n = n + 3
end
```

Comment: Thank you. This solution is great.

Comment: I just have one small question. Following the final example, I find that I can still put `module M : M_type` in the MLI, even though the real definition of module `M` has module type `EXT`, not `M_type`. What explains this? I can see that `EXT` includes `M_type`, but is this what the compiler recognizes as well?

Comment: Exactly, module type constraints, `module M: Signature = …`, restrict the signature of the module. This allows to control the exposed API of a module by hiding internal implementation details. For instance, any module can be restricted to `sig end`: `module M : sig end = struct type t = A end` . More useful, it is quite idiomatic in OCaml to implement data structure as a module `M` that exposes an abstract type `t` and operation on this type. For instance, a module set, will be `module Set = sig type t val union; t -> t -> t … end = struct … end`, hiding the implementation of the type t.