# OCaml Double Semicolon Error in Toplevel

Tags: syntax-error, ocaml

I am receiving this odd syntax error in the OCaml toplevel.

```
# #use "ex_8_4.ml";;
type blob = {
  get : unit -> float * float;
  area : unit -> float;
  set : float * float -> unit;
  move : float * float -> unit;
}
val new_rectangle : float -> float -> float -> float -> blob = <fun>
# let rect1 = new_rectangle 0.0 0.0 1.0 1.0 in  
  let rect2 = {rect1 with set = (fun _ -> ())};;
Error: Syntax error
```

The copying failed to include that the semicolons are underlined in the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happens because the toplevel is expecting an `in` keyword instead of semicolons:

```
> let a = 1 in let b = 2;;
Error: Syntax error
```

One fix would be to add an `in` at the end:

```
> let a = 1 in let b = 2 in a + b;;
- : int = 3
```

But the simplest would be to end each let binding with semicolons:

```
> let a = 1;;
val a : int = 1
> let b = 2;;
val b : int = 2
> a + b;;
- : int = 3
```

Comment: Happens to me all the time. I wish OCaml syntax errors were a bit more expressive.

Comment: @RichouHunter I hear you. I've recently started using OCaml and was basically shocked that "Syntax error" is the whole error message we're giving when something goes wrong with the syntax. And this particular one with a missing `in` token is obnoxious. I've recently lost 10 minutes tracking down one such error.

Comment: Just a quick comment to thank you, Ionut, for editing the tags in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44470095/further-refining-the-signature-of-a-nested-module-in-the-signature-of-the-parent/44470369#44470369 (I didn't know where to put my thanks elsewhere but I'll delete this comment after a while ;-))

Answer (score 0):

Ionuț G. Stan's answer is correct if what you want to define `rect1` for future use, or if you don't mind that it's defined.  If you wanted `rect1` to be defined only for local use in defining `rect2`, you could use this method:

```
# type ints = {a : int;  b : int};;
(* type ints = { a : int; b : int; } *)
# let y =
   let x = {a = 1; b = 2} in
   {x with b = 5};;
(* val y : ints = {a = 1; b = 5} *)
# x;;
(* Error: Unbound value x *)
```